# View.setBackground() setting background of ImageButton?

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton 
android:id="@+id/nextPageB"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="True"
android:contentDescription="@string/nextPage"
android:onClick="NextPage"
android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
/>
```

This is part of a seperate activity that is started from my main activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, BookRead.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Once in the new activity I call the NextPage method upon ImageButton click:

```
public void NextPage(View view)
{
    view.setBackgroud(res.getDrawable(R.Drawable.MyNewImage));
}
```

'res' is defined in my new activity in the onCreate method:

```
res = this.getResources();
```

For some reason when I click my ImageButton it changes the background on the ImageButton itself instead of the activity layout.

Comment: Try printing out `view`. What does it return? It's probably passing in the button instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An imagebutton is also a view, and you are probably passing the imagebutton view to the NextPage method.

You could either get the correct view by referencing it from XML or do something like view.getParent().

Comment: That did it!  Thank you!.  I used: View parentView = (View)view.getParent();  Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

The onClick method receives the view which is actually clicked.